# Nginx default librenms PHP page blank

Tags: php, nginx

I have a default LibreNMS install on a fresh Debian Jessie server running nginx, but the default landing page (since there's no other virtual hosts) just shows a blank page. My nginx config in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default is like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;
    root        /opt/librenms/html;
    index       index.php;
    access_log  /opt/librenms/logs/access_log;
    error_log   /opt/librenms/logs/error_log;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @librenms;
    }
    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location @librenms {
            rewrite api/v0(.*)$ /api_v0.php/$1 last;
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
}
```

The nginx -t passed, and nothing in `/opt/librenms/logs/error_log`, just an entry showing the browser I accessed from in `/opt/librenms/logs/access_log`. netstat shows nginx listening on port 80. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I never got Nginx working, but switched to Apache2.4 and got it working in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am using LibreNMS on ubuntu/nginx server without any problem

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;
    root        /opt/librenms/html;
```

Could you change the this part (given above) of your conf, after backing up, like below.

```
 listen      80;
 server_name 192.168.X.X;
 root        /opt/librenms/html;
```

Please don't forget to change server name IP address to your server IP.
Then please reload.

```
# nginx -t
# nginx -s reload
```